# Sum and Group by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table defined as such:

```
Name - Order# - Widget Count
Bob  - 12311  - 6
Nancy- 12555  - 8
BoB  - 87573  - 12
Nancy- 12929  - 4
```

I'd like to retrieve them as such:

```
Bob - 18
Nancy - 12
```

Ie: A sum of their widget counts, ordered by name. I know how to go about this in SQL server/etc, but I'm not sure what the best practice is in Rails. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work, assuming your model is called Person:

```
Person.group(:name).count(:widget_count)
```

You can find more info about it on [RailsGuides for ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#count).

Comment: Thanks! It seems to do what I want, but how can I call the results? I keep getting 'undefined method' errors.

Comment: @TheSciz: That should give you a Hash back, what are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting an array back, which does the job, but I'd hoped it would be cleaner... a hash, for example.

Comment: I certainly get an instance of `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`. You should be able to get the result by calling, say, `result['Bob']`. Does that work?

Comment: This answer may have a typo in it. It should be `sum`, not `count`: `Person.group(:name).sum(:widget_count)`